# Moving two strings through a list of words to compare each word

Tags: c++, string, unique

I am trying to use two strings to compare a list of words. For example, if someone inputs the words `"Hello Man Tomato Yum Zebra"` I want to set my two vectors to be the first two words, then move the two vectors up. S1 would be `hello` then S2 would be `Man`. After comparing them and moving the vectors, S1 would now be `Man` and S2 would be `Tomato`. Keep doing this until I reach the last two words, and when I do, print out all the unique words we saw.

Only thing is I cannot store the entire list of words in a string and not using sets, vectors, or maps.

Let me know if you need more details or some of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace::std;

int main(){
string S;
string V;
string Unique;
string Dup;
cin >> S;
cin >> V;
int temp;
//For unique strings
if (S.length() != V.length()){
    Unique += S;
    Unique += ' ';
    Unique += V;
}
else if (S[0] != V[0]){
        Unique += S;
        Unique += ' ';
        Unique += V;
}
//for dup strings
else if (S[0] == V[0]){
    for (int i=1; i < S.length(); ++i){
        if (S[i] != V[i]) {
        //if there is a letter that does match they are not duplicates so     add them to unique
         Unique += S;
         Unique += ' ';
         Unique += V;
         break;
            }
        temp = i;
    // this will break when it finds it's a dup or when i reaches the length of S and they are duplicates
    }    
        if (temp ==  S.length()-1){
    cout << "Duplicate string" << endl;
           }

    }
//cout the unique words
for (int i=0; i < Unique.length(); i++){
cout << Unique[i];
    }
 cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So essentially I am taking in two strings and comparing them to see if they are unique or duplicate. ***I want to be able to move vectors through input of more than two words, how would I have the vectors moving throughout the entire input without saving the entire input?***

The expected output for an input of 3 words `"Hello Hello Man"` would be just `"Man"` since it is the only unique word.

Comment: You can store a list of the unique words though, right?  If that is the case what you want is a `std::set`.

Comment: This is a help with coding site. show us the code you need help with please.

Comment: Once you have found [The most elegant way to iterate the words of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/the-most-elegant-way-to-iterate-the-words-of-a-string) then just loop to look at the words at index (i) and (i+1) and put them in a std::set.

Comment: Try to do it a C++ way, using `std::string`, `std::vector`, and others... When that's working, dumb it down to suit your teacher. In that way, you will be less likely to acquire bad habits. Why did I never think of that suggestion before?

Comment: What's the reason for comparing word neighbors ?  What do you use the outcome of the comparison for ?
What is the expected output for your example word list ?  What other cases do you have ?
Also, show your code.

Comment: Not just "some of code".- Post a [MCVE].  Read [ask].  You also need more comprehensive examples of input and expected output.  And what does "comparing them" mean? Checking for repeats like "Man Man"?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: @SidS I updated with expected output, the outcome of the comparison is just a list of the unique words nothing special. The input is in sorted order so I only have to compare the words next to each other.

Comment: That's progress. Now, what's your question?  Re-read [ask].

Comment: Will your teacher let you define functions?

Comment: @JiveDadson I just updated it. And yes, I don't see why not. Only rules were no vectors, sets, or maps. I also cannot store the entire list of words.

Comment: That code is only a fragment. It will not compile. Re-read how to post a [MCVE].

Comment: @JiveDadson I added the #include's and the main. Does that compile for you now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a function that with each successive call generates the next word from the input.
In a loop, have two calls that compare the last word with the next word until the end of the input is reached.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

//global variables; when updated
//return the next word from nextWord function
int start, space;

string nextWord(string wordList)
{
    //find the next space
    space = wordList.find(" ", space+1);
    //find the next word
    string word = wordList.substr(start, space-start);
    //restrict the search range
    start = space + 1;
    return word;
}
int main()
{
    //set initial values
    string words;
    getline(cin, words);
    string last = nextWord(words);
    string next;

    while (true)
    {
        if (space == -1)
            break;
        next = nextWord(words);
        if (last == next){
            cout << next << endl;
        }
        last = next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```